# <div> Relative Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have the following.

[full code link](http://jsfiddle.net/fMtkB/2/)

```
.rent-roll-container {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
.rent-roll-month-nav {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.rent-roll-table {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see there is a table, with two divs/columns on the left and right for navigating. All this is in one main container. I want everything to align across the top and the table to fill as much of the parent as possible. Also the height of all elements inside the main container should match.

Right now everything is scrunched to the left, with the navigation divs/columns anchored to the bottom. What is going on? How do I fix this. I have tried everything. I am trying to avoid fixing position or size, as I want dynamic sizing.

Comment: Not a big problem, make your box aligned.

Comment: How? I have explored quite a few attributes. "aligned" seems to be depreciated for HTML 5. Not that it was working for me anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for, try using `float`, and `width`.

Like here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMtkB/5/)

Comment: Lots, of help thanks! I still don't know how to get those side columns to match the main container height. Any suggestions?

Comment: add height in pixels to the container and specify a percent height for the container's children [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMtkB/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Use percentage widths and floats. Also you'd probably want a div here not a span.

http://jsfiddle.net/wf55h/

**css**

```
.rent-roll-container {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
.rent-roll-month-nav {
    background: blue;
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
.rent-roll-table {
    background: red;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="rent-roll-container">
    <div class="rent-roll-month-nav">
        <p>PRE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rent-roll-table">
        <table class="table table-striped text-center">
            <thead class="text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <th>Tenant(s)</th>
                    <th>Rent</th>
                    <th>Late</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                    <td>sdaf</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="rent-roll-month-nav">
        <p>NXT</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lots, of help thanks! I still don't know how to get those side columns to match the main container height. Any suggestions?

Comment: They'll expand when you add content to them. Otherwise you can set them to a fixed height. Please accept this as the answer if this is what you needed :)